# PHP: func_get_args performance?

Tags: php, performance

I'm about to use `func_get_args` for reading additional arguments of a function call.

How does this affect the performance? Should I rather use an array for passing additional arguments instead of reading them with the function above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless you are using it in mass quantities, no single function will make that much difference. You could always check how long it takes to call by using `microtime()` before and after the call, but I don't think you'll find anything interesting.

Go ahead and use it if you'd like.

I'd be more worried about making sure other programmers understand how the function works and knowing that they can pass any number of arguments to the function.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I rather use an array for passing additional arguments instead of reading them with the function above?

Yes, but more for a reason of clarity and code correctness, not so much performance. Example:

```
function foo($a) { }
foo(); // Warning: Missing argument 1 for foo()

function foo() { list($a) = func_get_args(); }
foo(); //no error
```

Also, when you see `foo($a)` you know immediately what to pass.

The only reason to use `func_get_args` is when you want a function with an arbitrary number of arguments (printf-like).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your performance will be noticeably different; it really comes down to preference.

*"Whatever floats your boat"*

Answer (score 1):

There are only those 2 possibilities, as far as I know. func_get_args is from my pov the more clean way.
I use this snippet with a parser (func_parameter) heavily to get an extra flexibility. There is just a small performance reduction. Probably not noteable.

It is like the question for performance between double-quote and and single-quote. If you start thinking about it, you should rethink about PHP is the right decision in case of performance.

```
    $parameter = func_get_args();
    $parameter = $this->func_parameter("key,data,dispense=",$parameter);
    extract($parameter);
```

Comment: May be fun to write, but your reinvented parameter parsing surely won't be fun to maintain.

Comment: PHP still has a *runtime* performance difference between single and double quotes?

Comment: +1 for *If you start thinking about it, you should rethink if PHP is the right decision pertaining to performance.*

Answer (score -1):

I ran this code and using a function that uses `func_get_args` and `func_num_args` seems more expensive...

php -v:

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 13 2012 17:20:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
Output: 
php dynFuncArgListTest.php 
$StatTestTot: 14.194619178772
$DynTestTot: 33.246332645416
```

code:

```
<?php

define('NEWLINE', "\n");

$StatTestTot = 0;
$DynTestTot = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < 9000; ++$i) {
    $randBoolArr = CreateArrayWithRandomBoolValues(900);
    $StatTestTot += StatTest($randBoolArr);
    $DynTestTot += DynTest($randBoolArr);
    $StatTestTot += StatTest($randBoolArr);
    $DynTestTot += DynTest($randBoolArr);
    $StatTestTot += StatTest($randBoolArr);
    $DynTestTot += DynTest($randBoolArr);
    $StatTestTot += StatTest($randBoolArr);
    $DynTestTot += DynTest($randBoolArr);
}

echo '$StatTestTot: ' . $StatTestTot . NEWLINE;
echo '$DynTestTot: ' . $DynTestTot . NEWLINE;

function DynTest($randBoolArr) {
    $StartDynTest = GetMicrotimeTrue();
    foreach($randBoolArr as $aBool) {
        IsBoolAndTrueDyn($aBool);
    }
    $EndDynTest = GetMicrotimeTrue();
    $Dyndisplacement = $EndDynTest - $StartDynTest;
    //echo 'Dyn Test: ' . $Dyndisplacement . NEWLINE;
    return $Dyndisplacement;
}

function StatTest($randBoolArr) {
    $StartStatTest = GetMicrotimeTrue();
    foreach($randBoolArr as $aBool) {
        IsBoolAndTrue($aBool);
    }

    $EndStatTest = GetMicrotimeTrue();
    $Statdisplacement = $EndStatTest - $StartStatTest;
    //echo 'Stat Test: ' . $Statdisplacement . NEWLINE;
    return $Statdisplacement;
}


function GetMicrotimeTrue() { return microtime(true); }

function CreateArrayWithRandomBoolValues($size) {
    $output = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $size; ++$i) {
        $output[$i] = (rand(0, 1) === 0);
    }
    return $output;
}

function IsBoolAndTrue($input) {
    if(!is_bool($input) || $input !== true) { 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function IsBoolAndTrueDyn() {
    $num_args = func_num_args();
    if($num_args > 0) {
        $args = func_get_args();
        foreach($args as $arg) {
            if(!is_bool($arg) || $arg !== true) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

?>
```

Comment: Not really a useful answer without know which PHP versions you ran this against and also some evidence of timings, spec of machine etc.

Comment: PHP Version was added and this is so far IMHO the closest answer to the OP.